# I try using signals and the pause() function in c in my college homework but to no avail

Tags: c, signals

The following program is supposed to do this:

1. The main process should create a child process,which I will refer to as **main child** from now on for convenience,then wait for a SIGUSR2 signal, then send a SIGUSR1 signal to his child and grandchildren, then wait for his child and finally end.
2. The main child should do the following 4 times: create a child and wait for SIGUSR2. After that the process should send a SIGUSR2 to his father,then wait for SIGUSR1, then wait for his children to end and finally end.
3. The main child's children should print *Proceso "PID" listo*,then send a SIGUSR2 to the main child,then wait for SIGUSR1,then print *Señal capturada* and finally end.

However it just prints one PID and then it never ends unless I use CTRL^C.I've tried changing the order of the pause() fucntions but to no avail. Also this is homework for college and they said we can't use semaphores yet.

If you know Spanish here are the instructions:

• El proceso padre generará un proceso hijo, que será el proceso gestor.

• El proceso gestor creará N_PROC procesos hijos (los participantes en la competición) en un
bucle, esperando tras crear cada proceso a que éste le notifique que está preparado
enviándole la señal SIGUSR2 .

• Cada participante en la carrera, una vez activo y con la señal armada, imprimirá un mensaje
y avisará al gestor mediante la señal SIGUSR2 .

• El proceso gestor, cuando haya creado los N_PROC procesos hijos y éstos estén listos para la
competición, avisará al proceso padre de que está todo listo enviándole la señal SIGUSR2 .

• El proceso padre mandará al grupo entero de procesos la señal
de la competición).

• Cuando los participantes en la carrera reciban la señal
ya han capturado la señal, y terminarán.

• Cuando el proceso gestor reciba SIGUSR1 , terminará su ejecución sin dejar hijos huérfanos.

• El proceso padre esperará a que el proceso gestor termine y acabará él también.

Thanks in advance.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define N_PROC 4


void manejador_SIGUSR1(int sig) {
    printf("Señal capturada\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void manejador_SIGUSR2(int sig) {

}

int main(void){
    int i,pid[N_PROC+1];
    struct sigaction act;

    sigemptyset(&(act.sa_mask));
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    /* Se arma la señal SIGUSR1. */
    act.sa_handler = manejador_SIGUSR1;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    act.sa_handler = manejador_SIGUSR2;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR2, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    if((pid[0] = fork()) == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

    if(pid[0] == 0) {
        for(i=0;i<N_PROC;i++){
            if((pid[i+1] = fork()) == -1) {
                perror("fork");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
             }
            if(pid[i+1]==0){
                printf("Proceso %d listo\n",getpid());
                kill(SIGUSR2,getppid());
                pause();

            }

            else{
                pause();

            }

        }
        kill(SIGUSR2,getppid());
        pause();
        while(wait(NULL)>0);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }

    pause();
    kill(SIGUSR1,0);
    while(wait(NULL)>0);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `pause()` is the wrong tool for the job. Use `sigwait`/`sigwaitinfo`/`sigsuspend`. A couple more details over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190460/using-signals-in-a-child-process/55190889

Comment: At the very least you have the arguments to `kill` in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Your arguments to `kill` are swapped, as [@Arkku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204883/arkku) noted in the comments.  Your "main process" waits forever for a SIGUSR2 from its very first child, which it never receives.

---

**Aside**

Ha! An assignment about race conditions given in the language of races (la carrera, le señal de competición).  That's great.

If I understand correctly, the desired flow is something like this:

```
                         +--> [competitor]
                         +--> [competitor]
[starter] --> [manager] -+--> [competitor]
                         +--> [competitor]
```

1. *Starter* creates *manager*
2. *Manager* gets *competitors* to the starting line

   1. Create a *competitor*
   2. Wait for the *competitor* to indicate it is ready (SIGUSR2)
   3. Repeat for N_PROC *competitors* total
3. *Manager* tells the *starter* that *competitors* are ready (SIGUSR2)
4. *Starter* fires the [starting pistol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starting_pistol) (SIGUSR1 to *process group*)
5. *Competitors* race!
6. *Manager* process terminates after reaping all *competitors*.
7. *Starter* terminates after reaping *manager*.

Several things can go wrong here.  Notably, [@PSkocik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084774/pskocik)'s comment is right:  [you should use `sigwait` or similar functions to avoid unintended races](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190889/132382).  Also, please don't [use `printf` in a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler).